# Artifactory-oss-6.23.42 with Java 17 : ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/security/cert/internal/x509/X509V1CertImpl

Tags: java, artifactory

Installing Artifactory-oss-6.23.42

With Java 17.

When boot up i am getting following

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to generate and save private key and root certificate.
org.jfrog.security.ssl.CertificateGenerationException: Failed to generate signed certificate: Could not find class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/security/cert/internal/x509/X509V1CertImpl

Any suggestion how to fix this?
Is it issue with Java 17 or do i need to do something else?

Comment: Have you checked if it actually supports Java 17? Also, why not try the **latest** version (7.63.12 at this time)?

Comment: 6.x is EOL and doesn't support Java 17.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Not easy to install Artifactory 7x on Linux. Getting issues in booting up default setup for last 7 days and have only 2 days to go. Not much help available. Earlier we have 6X installed so can copy from there.

Comment: OK, I couldn't find docs for version 6.23.42 (though I didn't search too hard), but I rather suspect it requires Java 8. Version 7.0.0-7.3.2 required Java 11 (see [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/about-artifactory-releases), which makes me think that 6.x required a lower Java version.

Comment: OK, according to [JFrog Artifactory Version 6.0 User Guide](https://jfrog.com/help/v/u/jfrog-artifactory-version-6.0-user-guide), the requirement is _"Artifactory must run with JDK 8 (JDK 8 update 45 and above preferred) or JDK 11 (from Artifactory version 6.10)."_, so the upper limit is probably Java 11. It looks like Artifactory used one of the internal classes of Java, which they shouldn't have, and likely Java 17 (or some version in between) moved, removed or renamed that internal class or made it otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I downgraded to Java 11 and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Can you put it as answer i will select it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JFrog Artifactory Version 6.0 User Guide](https://jfrog.com/help/v/u/jfrog-artifactory-version-6.0-user-guide), the requirement is

> Artifactory must run with JDK 8 (JDK 8 update 45 and above preferred)
> or JDK 11 (from Artifactory version 6.10).

So, the upper limit for Artifactory 6 is Java 11. It looks like Artifactory used one of the internal classes of Java, which they shouldn't have, and likely Java 17 (or some version in between) moved, removed or renamed that internal class or made it otherwise inaccessible.

Alternatively, use Artifactory 7 instead, as recent versions of Artifactory 7 do support Java 17.